# Duplicate records appears in crystal report when saving or debugging

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, duplicates, copy, report

[image: Duplicated record appear as showed in the image]

I have a crystal report in visual studio. When im editing or using that report, if i click save. It will create a duplicate copy of that report. Then it will show a normal error message "There were build errors". I have to delete the duplicate record and save again, then debug then it works. I do not want to delete the duplicated record every-time i save that report. Does anyone know what the problem

Comment: this might be helpful https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1871166

Comment: @Mahendra Thank you, good info